# Getting a error for creating a app in react

Tags: reactjs, npm

I uninstalled both visual studio code and node js. Restarted machine. Installed again both visual studio and node js. But the problem is there.

```
PS D:\React> npm create-react-app myapp

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\ee209495\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.14.9 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

Comment: try `npx create-react-app myapp`

Comment: If I try with your command. Getting error
**Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock**

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed create-reat-app previously?

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Also, you can use npx so it would be using latest npm version

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to install `create-react-app` package globally

```
npm i -g create-react-app
create-react-app my app
```

or alternatively you can use npx to always use the latest version of CRA

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```